# Question about mod action taken

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

[Message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/36167085/history) that got me suspended... If you watch the video it is a clean funny video by Studio C and Studio C's goal is "to produce clean, family-oriented comedy for a national audience". I do not understand how that is worth of suspending me. I do not think noise applies since literally 5 messages ago Riker posted [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36166303#36166303) and it got 3 stars so it is not "offensive". Please help me understand as I feel like it was unjust. The thumbnail just shows a man in a mask so that is not offensive.

Comment: It looks to me like a man getting mugged/beat up.  That's offensive. And it doesn't really matter the contents of the video, the thumbnail was what was oneboxed in chat.

Comment: @Riker In a world of Arrow, Marvel, Batman v Superman, Jason Bourne, The Expanse, etc and you consider a Studio C video with cartoon level violence offensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag-deletion (by several 10k users and/or a moderator) shouldn't happen because of noise; that's what kicks and manual suspensions (for repeated offenders) are for.

That said, I'm not sure I agree with the assessment of *clean, family-oriented comedy for a national audience*. While you may not find someone getting tazed in the neck, shot in the leg, and repeatedly whacked on the head with flower pots offensive, others may and appareantly have. On top of that, the thumbnail looks a lot more gruesome than the actual video, so it is possible that is was deleted based on the thumbnail alone.

Your suspension is over, so at this point, there's nothing left to be done except moving on.

Comment: OK thanks. I never thought I would get suspended for thumbnail. I did not provide that assessment that was wikipidia. Also if that is offensive how is using strong language not? shouldn't that always be flagged?